# how do I get a Specific part of a web attribute in python with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, href

I need to get that part after window.open  ('/echipa/lok-moscova/Sjs63WfK') as a string
from this web element with selenium and I don't really know how to do it . if I can do it.

```
<a href="#" class="participant-imglink" onclick="window.open('/echipa/lok-moscova/Sjs63WfK'); return false;">Lok. Moscova</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example with BeautifulSoup (you can create soup object from selenium page source):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
    <a href="#" class="participant-imglink" onclick="window.open('/echipa/lok-moscova/Sjs63WfK'); return false;">Lok. Moscova</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

link = soup.select_one('a.participant-imglink[onclick]')
url = re.search(r"window\.open\('(.*?)'\)", link['onclick']).group(1)
print(url)
```

Prints:

```
/echipa/lok-moscova/Sjs63WfK
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the element in selenium. The easiest way is by id, by you can search by a lot of things (check more [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)).

```
linkElement = driver.findElement(By.id("id"))
```

Next, you can extract attribute as a string

```
text = linkElement.getAttribute("onclick");
```

and remove obsolete parts

```
text = text.replace("window.open(", "").replace(")", "")
```

and that would be your `"/echipa/lok-moscova/Sjs63WfK"`

Comment: but There is no ID  here : <a href="#" class="participant-imglink" onclick="window.open('/echipa/lok-moscova/Sjs63WfK'); return false;">Lok. Moscova</a>